GPU Passthrough qemu/virt-manager - Linux Host, Linux Guest
tl;dr - NixOS Linux host running qemu, configured with virt-manager. NixOS guest VM. Physical machine has two GPUs in their own IOMMU groups. Want to put the more powerful GPU into the NixOS guest for rendering / processing, but real-time is not important. Still use spice or window via virt-manager for display.

Most of the tutorials I am finding are for Windows GPU passthrough for gaming, etc. In my case, I want to run a very lightweight host OS that just hosts various VMS, containers, etc. One of these VMs will be my "daily driver" on NixOS. I plan to do some things like video encoding, rendering, etc. for which I want to take advantage of the GPU. I don't really care about "real-time", as long as audio and video come over spice/VNC/ etc at the same time for something like video editing -e.g., my needs would be okay if this was a remote connection with low latency.
I have run through a few different tutorials to try to get this to work. In one I saw you needed to dump bios, but this wasn't required in any other tutorials. What gets change in virt-manager seems to sometimes be different, etc. Maybe some of these are older or the changes are needed for Windows? Many of them seem to have the goal of using a second monitor or using looking-glass. I definitely do not want to use a second monitor, and I see some other "viewer" as overkill ontop of staying inside virt-manager (I essentially just run virt-manager on i3 and put the VM I am using in full screen, works great for my needs so far).
In one test I ended up with my host OS being inoperable and due to the system settings, the font was too small to read what was going on. In another, I get visual in the attached virt-manager viewer until it gets to what I assume is the log in part. Maybe if I set up another VNC or spice client I could log in there, but again would like to avoid that overhead.
I also read something, but couldn't quite find more documentation that explained it, but if I select "virtio" instead of QXL is is actually virtualizing the video card? Perhaps for Linux host + linux guest you don't need to "pass through"? But I thought maybe some apps may make use of specific "NVIDIA" features not available if virtualized? I also have the two video cards, so if possible, I might as well dedicate the one.
Essentially, I would like to understand what I can do to make the simplest setup with the least amount of dependencies (e.g., not looking-glass) to allow my Linux Guest to get all over the power of the GPU, but have the same experience as I currently have with virt-manager. Even better if this can be done using existing NixOS options or packages which are available. Also, since most of these tutorials talk about Windows, anything I need to do special on the linux guest VM would be helpful to call out.
